# Can't use a struct(with template) inside a class

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I made a node struct with a template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node{
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
};
```

It compiles fine but when I try to use it inside a class it gives me the error:
invalid use of template-name ‘Node’ without an argument list

Comment: Show us how you're using it then.

Comment: Wouldn't he just have to use template argument for the Node*? 

    Node<T>* next
    Node<T>* prev

Answer (score 2):

In another class' context, you need to add a template parameter instead of using plain `Node*`:

```
struct B
{
  Node<int>* next;
};
```